# About showing algorithmic gap instance for the Goemans-Williamson SDP

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, approximation

Using usual notation we have,

$SDP(G) \geq OPT(G) \geq Alg_{GW}(G) \geq \alpha_{GW} SDP(G) \geq \alpha_{GW} OPT(G)$

where we mean,

$SDP(G)$ = The maximum value that the SDP finds of the objective function $\sum_{(u,v) \in E} w_{uv}( 1-\vec{y_u}.\vec{y_v})/2$  (one unit vector $\vec{y_v}$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ for each vertex $v$ for some $d$) And $w_{uv}$ are the given edge weights such that $\sum_{(u,v) \in E} w_{uv} =1$

$OPT(G)$ = The actual size of the max-cut for the graph

$Alg_{GW}(G)$ = The value of the max-cut returned by the randomized rounding prescription of Goemans-Williamson

$\alpha_{GW}$ = the famous constant of $\sim 0.878$

- If say someone shows that for every $\epsilon$ there is a graph $G(\epsilon)$ such that $(\alpha_{GW}+\epsilon)OPT(G(\epsilon)) \geq Alg_{GW}(G(\epsilon))$ then does this imply that this is a class of graphs on which the algorithm is performing as bad as it could?
- Why does showing the existence of such a family of graphs as above also  necessarily imply that on this family $SDP(G(\epsilon)) = OPT(G(\epsilon))$ ?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Can you edit the question to add some context?  You use a bunch of symbols without defining any of them.  Also, please edit the question to ask only one question.  This site doesn't work well for multiple questions per question.  Ask your first question, and then see what answers you get; based on the answers, you might then be able to answer your subsequent questions, or you might be in a better position to ask your second question at that time.  Also, please show us what you've tried, what your thoughts are, what approaches you've considered and why you rejected them.

Comment: I have reformatted the question. Hopefully this looks better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A graph for which $Alg(G) = \beta OPT(G)$ is, by definition, a graph on which the algorithm has approximation ratio $\beta$. You can use this insight to answer the first question.

As to your second question, suppose that $Alg(G) \leq (\alpha_{GW}+\epsilon) OPT(G)$. Since $Alg(G) \geq \alpha_{GW} SDP(G)$, we deduce that
$$
\alpha_{GW} SDP(G) \leq Alg(G) \leq (\alpha_{GW}+\epsilon) OPT(G).
$$
Therefore $SDP(G) \leq (1+O(\epsilon)) OPT(G)$.

Comment: Yes. This I understand. But I am not able to see the equivalence between showing that (1) for this set of graphs it is always true that $SDP(G) \leq (1+O(\epsilon) )OPT(G)$ for all $\epsilon$ and (2) the claim that $SDP$ and $OPT$ match on this set. Aren't these two things different? (except that if someone also shows that there really does exist a graph precisely at $\epsilon = 0$ then only for that graph I would think that one can legitimately say that SDP and OPT match. right?)

Comment: The claim is just wrong. You can't deduce it in general. Perhaps for these particular graphs, equality holds, but you can only deduce this by considering the actual graphs.

Comment: Can you have a look at the first line of section 4 of these notes, http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~anupamg/adv-approx/lecture16.pdf  where it says, "We now focus on the second question —
that of the algorithmic gap: Are there instances G where AlgGW (G) ≤ (αGW + )Opt(G) (for any constant epsilon)? Note that such instances would imply that Sdp(G) = Opt(G)" What do they mean?

Comment: Like, they start off trying to show that there exists a family of graphs for which,  $\alpha_{GW} SDP(G) \leq Alg(G) \leq (\alpha_{GW}+\epsilon) OPT(G)$ but they say that for this same class of graphs $SDP = OPT = Obj$! If all these 3 quantities are coinciding then how is this class of graphs the "worst" case for GW? (as they set out to show initially!) (..infact for this class Obj = OPT always and hence there seems to be nothing for the SDP to optimize!..)

Comment: For these graphs it so happens that SDP equals OPT. This requires proof, which you can probably find in the lecture notes. On the other hand, you lose a lot in the rounding.

Comment: So the fact that for these graphs $SDP = OPT$ is an independent fact from the fact that for this set of graphs $\alpha_{GW} OPT \leq \alpha_{GW} SDP (G) \leq Alg(G) \leq (\alpha_{GW} +\epsilon) OPT (G)$ ? The later shows that this is an "algorithmic gap instance" irrespective of the first equality?

Comment: Right, the inequality only shows that $SDP \approx OPT$.

Comment: ^But that is enough to call it an "algorithmic gap instance"? Or is the equality needed to be proven to call it so?

Comment: There is no formal definition of *algorithmic gap instance*. Use your common sense and judgement.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, this is how I am organizing this "definition" in my head : we start off with these two facts (Fact 1) That $1 \leq ``Integrality Gap'' = sup [ SDP/OPT] \leq SDP/Alg_{GW} \leq 1/\alpha_{GW}$ and (Fact 2) $SDP \geq OPT \geq Alg_{GW} = \mathbb{E}[ GW cut-size] \geq \alpha_{GW} SDP \geq \alpha_{GW} OPT$.

Comment: Now we can look for 2 things (1) The "Integrality Gap Instance" i.e examples where SDP/OPT is as *high* as possible (i.e ~ $1/\alpha_{GW}$) and thus making $OPT \sim Alg_{GW}$. This is curiously shown by showing, $(\alpha_{GW} + \epsilon )SDP \geq OPT$ for some class. (2) ``Algorithmic Gap Instance" i.e examples where SDP/OPT is as *low* as possible (i.e $~ 1$) and thus making $SDP \sim OPT$ and this is curiously shown by showing that $(\alpha_{GW} + \epsilon)OPT \geq Alg_{GW}$ for some class.

Comment: This is all explained very clearly in Anupam Gupta's lecture notes that you mention.

Comment: I thought his lecture notes were very confusing! So I summarized the definition above as I understood it to check if I am getting it right. Anupam is never clearly stating this thing as I tried to flesh out above...