# Is there a degree-2 SOS rewriting of the Goemans-Williamson rounding?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, optimization, np-hard

I use the same notation as I used in this previous question, [About showing algorithmic gap instance for the Goemans-Williamson SDP](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/52624/about-showing-algorithmic-gap-instance-for-the-goemans-williamson-sdp) The same definition continue.

Given a $f : \{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ one defines a quantity called $\overline{sos}_d(f)$ which is the smallest $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that one can find functions on the Boolean hypercube $g_1,g_2,..,g_t : \{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ for some $t$ with $deg(g_i) \leq d/2$ such that on the Boolean hypercube we have the equality, $c -f = \sum_{i=1}^{t} g_i ^2$

So one would say that $\overline{sos}_d(f)$ is the minimum $c$ such that the inequality $c-f \geq 0$ has a ``degree-d SOS certificate" on the Boolean hypercube.

Now one claims that the GW algorithm for Max-Cut is "based on the upperbound $\overline{sos}_2(f)$" and this in equation means that for the objective function of Max-Cut $f_{Max-Cut(G)} = \sum_{(i,j) \in E(G) } (x_i -x_j)^2$ we have,

$max(f_{Max-Cut(G)}) \geq \alpha_{GW} \overline{sos}_2(f_{Max-Cut(G)})$

- Is the above some immediate consequence of the GW analysis?  Can someone kindly help recast that as this inequality if this is indeed true?
- Or if this inequality requires a separate proof then can someone kindly reference that? I haven't been able to find that..
- Do we know anything about say showing something like,

$max(f_{Max-Cut(G)}) \geq (\alpha_{GW} + \text{something positive}) \overline{sos}_{\text{something greater than} 2 }(f_{Max-Cut(G)})$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The quadratic sum-of-squares relaxation of Max-Cut should indeed work out to be equivalent to the SDP that Goemans and Williamson solve. I encourage you to work this out yourself. This means that the Goemans-Williamson analysis indeed shows the inequality you mention.

You ask whether degree-2 SoS is a rewriting of the Goemans-Williamson rounding. It isn't. Rounding is a completely separate issue. Degree-2 SoS is a rewriting of the SDP that Goemans and Williamson solve. Rounding is how we bound the integrality gap.

Assuming the Unique Games Conjecture, $\alpha_{GW}$ is the optimal approximation ratio achievable in polynomial time. Since optimizing degree $d$ sum-of-squares can be done in time $O(n^{O(d)})$, this implies (assuming UGC) that every *constant* degree $d$ has the same integrality gap $\alpha_{GW}$ in the worst case.

Comment: (1) I don't see the relation between the SDP that the GW rounds and what you call the "quadratic sos relaxation of Max-Cut".  Also the SDP doesn't know the 0.878 thing since that comes from the GW rounding - that makes it more non-obvious as to how the SDP alone can give this SOS inequality which seems to know the 0.878 thing. (2) I know this UGC statement - but I wonder if on any special but non-trivial class of graphs this 0.878 has been improved by a degree > 2 SOS (or maybe even by a degree = 2 SOS)

Comment: I mean one can always write down a SDP formulation of the question of finding the Lassere map at degree 2 for the max-cut constraints - but that is yet another SDP than the SDP that Max-Cut rounds - how is the SDP alone going to know this 0.878 thing?

Comment: For (2), take a look at this survey: https://www.math.washington.edu/~rothvoss/lecturenotes/lasserresurvey.pdf.

Comment: For (1), $\alpha_{GW}$ is the integrality gap of the Goemans-Williamson relaxation. It's a property relaxation, not of the rounding.

Comment: Also, you can take a look at notes of Barak: http://www.boazbarak.org/sos/files/lec2d.pdf. However, I encourage you to work this out yourself. This is the only way to really understand it.

Comment: I would think that one relaxes (to the vector program) and then rounds by the GW method and tries to find how close one can get to the optimal by this and then the 0.878 approximation factor shows up. And none of this is known to the SDP - and hence its not clear why say a different SDP the one that the Lassere question would imply should know this 0.878 factor. It would be great if you have a reference which explains this connection!

Comment: You are wrong. Denoting by OPT and SDP the maximum cut and the objective value of the Goemans-Williamson SDP, since the SDP is a relaxation then OPT$\leq$SDP, and the rounding implies that $\alpha_{GW}$SDP$\leq$OPT. This is a property of the SDP solution that you can prove by rounding, but it exists regardless of the rounding.

Comment: Is there any way to show that $\alpha_{GW} SDP \leq OPT$ without going through the hyperplane rounding? You have any reference which does something like this? I have never seen this...

Comment: I am not aware of any alternative proof.

Comment: But isn't exactly something like that being claimed in the SOS picture? That the SOS picture somehow directly knows this? (..like I have no idea what is the analogue of "hyperplane rounding" or anything like that in the SOS picture!..)

Comment: You can round solutions of constant degree SoS relaxations, this is explained in the survey of Rothvoss. I don't know what you mean by "the SoS picture somehow directly knows this". Please take the time to read the material I sent you before asking any more questions.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! Let me see. Nothing I have seen till now (the papers mostly and Barak's lecture notes) explain anything like this. They typically totally avoid talking of the SDP formulation of the positivellensatz!